# Offline push notification - reminder feature

Tags: android, notifications

I'm interested in adding notifications to my application, in the form of reminders.

I've looked into notifications, but I have yet to find a way to do it without the app being open.

For example, I want to add a time setting, that will store the time in day to send the notification.

Then, each day (or w\e), at the given time, I want the user to receive a notification, which he can click to enter the application.

How is it done?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a `AlarmManager` based program to schedule your application's calls and then send Local Notifications to the UI with `NotificationCompat.Builder`
Have a look at the link below, it will get you started easily
http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 0):

Even better, you may want to look into [GCMNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager) which is another great way for scheduling tasks to happen at a specific time.

You shouldn't need the App to be running for either Alarms, or other scheduled events to occur.  There are few different options for generating timed events to trigger the notification.

Here is an example, you would set the PendingIntent to start you notification:

```
    private void setAlarm() {
        final AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        final Intent i = new Intent(this, MyNotifService.class);
        final PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
        am.cancel(pi);

        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        final String notifTime = prefs.getString("notif_time", "07:30");
        final String[] times = notifTime.split(":");
        final int hour = Integer.parseInt(times[0]);
        final int min = Integer.parseInt(times[1]);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);

        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
  }
```

Comment: But theb u have to be connected to the net for that

Comment: You don't have to be Net connected to use GCMNetworkManager - this is for sure a fine way to schedule tasks.

Comment: And to use this, do I have to understand services? does it basically start a service?

Comment: Yes, this PendingIntent starts a Service (in this case it is named: MyNotifService) that will do whatever you want (in my case I display a notification).